# Как этот скрипт обработать AJAX'ом?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Это js код

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".delimage").click(function () {
        id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_delete_comments.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                $("#comment" + id).hide('slide', 1000); //Ну или hide(), если хочется его только скрыть
            } //Удаление 
        });
    });
    $(".delimage").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/delete_comment2.png");
    });

    $(".delimage").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/delete_comment.png");
    });

});
</script>
```

вот обрабатываемый файл `ajax_delete_comments.php`

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","*****");
    mysql_select_db("*****",$db);
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){$id = $_POST['id'];}
    mysql_query("DELETE * FROM comments WHERE post='$id'",$db);
?>
```

Вопрос вот в чем. Есть какие-то комментарии по нажатию на крестик, они должны исчезать и происходить удаление из бд (код мой не работает, видимо, я что-то не так делаю).

Comment: Вопрос вообще непонятен, есть Jquery с запросом, есть файл  обработчик, что не работает?

Comment: удаление из базы не происходит

Comment: Офиенно грамотно поставлен вопрос. Типа если дать по голове монтировкой какой шнурок развяжется? Я уже молчу о том что тут прямая уязвимость во все красе. Это же уметь надо! Не просто дыру просверлить в скрипте! Но и позаботиться о том чтобы хакер не забыл переменную на сервер отправить! И даже в этом деле блеснуть! Если он ее не отправил то мы несуществующую переменную зафигачим в запрос! Бойся хакер! Тебе такое во сне не приснится даже!

Comment: Arni не можете помочь не надо идите ругаться в другое место

Comment: .attr("data-id") замени на .data('id')

Comment: Я вам уже помог. Но вы настолько сильно принимаете это как оскорбление что даже не заметили что я сообщил вам целый ряд проблем. Ваш вопрос, который звучит в теме, никак не связан с вашей проблемой. Учитесь выражаться, я вам не минус в репутацию поставил, хотя могу. Я вам делаю замечание. С таким отношением, вы можете не надеяться даже на помощь. И тем более на уважение. И кстати, ошибку вывести трудно что-ли и посмотреть на что именно ругается в запросе?

Comment: да не знаю(может подскажите?)

Comment: Четвертый вопрос на один и тот же скрипт. А этот вопрос говорит о том, что Вы понятия не имеете, что написали. Может все-таки откроете справки jquery, php и mysql? А еще не помешает разузнать о способах отладки всех трех составляющих.

Comment: А я вроде 5 нашел :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ты забыл id передать

```
   $.ajax({  
        url: "ajax_delete_comments.php",
        data: 'id=' + id,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,  
        success: function(){ 
                    $("#comment"+id).hide('slide',1000); 
                 }
    });
```

Comment: хмм не работает
что я еще не так делаю?

Comment: Вообще сложно сказать, что не так, видя малую часть приложения, но попробуй ещё звёздочку убрать в 

    mysql_query("DELETE * FROM comments WHERE post='$id'",$db);

лично я всегда без неё делаю удаление.

Comment: да нет не работает

Comment: может я так считаю(перменная id не передается или я неправильно написал обрабатываемый файл)

Comment: Если хочешь убедиться, что id передался, пропиши в php

    print_r($_POST);  

оно выведет тебе всё, что было передано, и ещё используй

    mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());  
  
только юзай инспектор хрома, у него во вкладке нетворк будут показаны все твои xhr со всеми отправлеными данными и получеными ответами.

Comment: спс через нетворк хрома вывело следующее 
Array
(
    [id] => 349
)
методом print_r($_POST);

Comment: значит всё приходт, проверь работу с базой данных в скрипте

Comment: все заработало надо было запрос дописать правильнее